# Error while creating python UDF in Redshift

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create Python UDF in Amazon Redshift, and I have successfully created the UDF with no error. I have also created the required library for this UDF successfully. But when I execute the UDF, I get the error:

> No Module Named pyffx. Please look at svl_udf_log for more information

I have downloaded the library from `pypi.org` and uploaded it to Amazon S3. This is the link I used to download the library:

https://pypi.org/project/pyffx/#files

```
create library pyffx
language plpythonu
from 's3://aws-bucket/tmp/python_module/pyffx-0.3.0.zip'
credentials
'aws_iam_role=iam role'
region 'us-east-1';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.ffx(src VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
STABLE
AS $$
    import pyffx
    src = unicode(src)
    value=(src)
    l=len(value)
    e = pyffx.String(b'secret-key', alphabet='abcedefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', length=l)
    return e.encrypt(value)
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Comment: Did the `create library pyffx` command execute without error? And, presumably, you put your actual IAM Role in the `credentials` line? Did you convert the `pyffx-0.3.0.tar.gz` file into a `.zip` format?

Comment: yes, create library pyffx executed without error. yes, i have put actual IAM Role in the credentials. yes, i converted the .tar.gz to .zip using below online convertor tool.     https://www.zamzar.com/convert/tar-to-zip/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work... sort of.

I did the following:

- Downloaded pyffx via the link you provided
- Extracted the `.tar.gz` file and created a `.zip` of the files
- Copied the `.zip` file to Amazon S3
- Loaded the library using your `CREATE LIBRARY` command
- Created the function

However, when I use the function, I receive the error:

> Invalid operation: AttributeError: **'module' object has no attribute 'add_metaclass'**

My research suggests that the `six` library (that provides Python 2 and 3 compatibility) is the source of this problem. The [Python Language Support for UDFs - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-python-language-support.html) page indicates that `six 1.3` is included in Redshift, yet [Pip six.add_metaclass error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50827476/174777) says that this version does not include `add_metaclass`. The current version of `six` is 1.12.

I tried to include an updated `six` library in the code but wasn't successful. You might be able to wrangle better than me.

Comment: i uploaded six library to the redshift and import the six library in my code, i still get same error: "no module pyffx".      CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.ffx(src VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
STABLE
AS $$
    import pyffx
    src = unicode(src)
    value=(src)
    l=len(value)
    e = pyffx.String(b'secret-key', alphabet='abcedefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', length=l)
    return e.encrypt(value)
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;

Comment: How did you upload the `six` library? When I tried to `CREATE LIBRARY` for `six`, it complained that it already existed. Loading the library under a different name didn't change my error message.

Comment: I followed the same process i did for creating pyffx library. download the file and load to s3 and create the Six library.

Comment: But it is not permissible to create a library with the same name as an existing library. Did you use `CREATE LIBRARY six`?

Comment: yes, I did CREATE LIBRARY SIX. i think issue is with the version of this package; pyffx is compatible with python 3, however Redshift is using python 2.7. what is your thoughts?